# How do i align multiple columns in excel by name and sales?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, sorting

Please ref attached image.

I need to align sales for the agents in single row to match their names. The problem is that in Jan the number 1 agent may be on 5th spot and in 12th place in the third month. I need to bring the agent and his corresponding sales in one row.

[image: Excel Sample]

Comment: Do you have the same agents in all months? If yes, then simply sort each month alphabetically. If not, then best way would be to copy agent names to a new sheet, then use `VLOOKUP` to match sales. Is this the format you receive your data? If not, then sharing your original format we may suggest something easier.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have the same agents in all months. Here's a technique:

1. Move Columns D and E to a new sheet (`Sheet2`) and F and G to another (`Sheet3`).
2. Arrange all three sheets alphabetically. Here's how:

   - Select the names column on each `Sheet1`.
   - Go to `Data` tab.
   - In the `Sort & Filter` group, click the `Sort A to Z` button. Both the Agent name and sales columns will be sorted according to the alphabetical order of names.
   - Repeat procedure with `Sheet2` and `Sheet3` so all sheets are sorted by alphabetical order of names.
3. Move the data of `Sheet2` and `Sheet3` back into `Sheet1`.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution may be to insert enough columns after 'C' to allow for the number of quarters being reported. 
Then, in each column from 'D' to 'col n', use a vlookup of the name from 'B' to find that name's corresponding value from 'D' and 'E' (which will be different columns than shown as you have inserted more columns. 
Then, each name in 'B' will show their relative sales by quarter.